# idea plugin jprofiler com.jprofiler.integrations.idea.graph.n.daemonCancelEventOccurred(Ljava/lang

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jprofiler

idea use plugin jprofiler error msg com.jprofiler.integrations.idea.graph.n.daemonCancelEventOccurred

Comment: Please report a bug at support@ej-technologies.com. The issue is with the https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/253-jprofiler/ plug-in.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your problem. Unable to understand from the title or the description.

Comment: The feeling is that the plug-in's dependencies conflict

Comment: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.jprofiler.integrations.idea.graph.n.daemonCancelEventOccurred(Ljava/lang/String;)V
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

Comment: I also installed a jreble

Comment: I lowered the version  17.1.4

Comment: Try add some description to your problem like which version are you using, what do you intend to do and when you get this error

Comment: Plugin jrebel version 2019.1.6 ，jprofiler version 1.8 there is no separate test to see if there is a problem with just installing jprofiler，  The jprofiler plug-in reported problems while using the jrebel hot deployment，Plug-in jprofiler back to version 17 is no problem.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ IDEA do you use?

Comment: Version of idea used 2018 -1.8